# JStree more than one link per leaf

Tags: jquery, jstree

How do I get to have two links inside a jstree leaf.

I want to display a little image as a link that redirects to the help document that corresponds to a leaf in a jstree but when I add a second link inside the `<li>` element, jstree treats it as a leaf. I guess to solve the issue I can use another tag for displaying  the image and onclick go to somewhere. Something like

```
<div title="pathToHelpDocument" onclick="javascript:goToHelpDocument()">
</div>
```

But it just does not seem elegant at all. Which is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [jsTreeGrid](https://github.com/deitch/jstree-grid) plugin.